# SQL Server Filestream with django-mssql

Tags: sql-server, django, django-models, sqlfilestream, django-mssql

I would like to use SQL Server Filestream feature to store files (mainly large images) from a Django application.
Currently I am using django-mssql as the database backend for my Django project. I don't think there is any existing model field in that package that is linked to a Filestream column in SQL Server.

What would be the best way to use the filestream feature from Django ? Are there any existing packages ? Or do I need to implement my own custom model field, inherited from Django's built-in fields (FileField or BinaryField) ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case anyone else is interested in using SQL Server Filestream feature, and ends up here, I started working on custom django Fields to support Filestream : a `FileStreamDataField` that maps to the `varbinary(max) FILESTREAM` type and a `FileStreamField` which is a virtual field that wraps the win32 Streaming API.

```
import uuid

from django.db import models
from sql_filestream import FileStreamDataField, FileStreamField, UUIDField

class DocumentModel(models.Model):
    doc_id = UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    doc_content = FileStreamDataField(identifier_field='doc_id', null=True, blank=True)
    document = FileStreamField('doc_id', 'doc_content')
```

You can find it with examples here : https://github.com/rparent/django-mssql-filestream
It works well my use case but is certainly incomplete. 
Contributions welcome !

Comment: Wow thanks you just saved me a couple of months of headache!